# Is my space a good candidate for a hybrid electric heat pump water heater?

Tags: water, water-heater, utilities

We're purchasing a condo, and the current water heater is almost 10 years old. I don't know that it needs replaced (I'll be researching replacing the anode next), but if it does, I'd like something more efficient.  I think I'm sold on hybrid. They don't seem like much work, and I definitely want to have something more efficient.

I've attached a photo of the room where the water heater is located. My only concern is the condensate line required for hybrid tanks. Could I tie it in at the clothes washer drain?

[image: utility room]

Comment: Depending on the quality of that heater, it should be middle aged.  Your use of hot water will be the the deciding factor if changing to a different type of heater is worth it, cost plus/minus savings.

Comment: Is this room heated space? your hybrid water heater will be pulling heat from the room it is in, so if this room is inside your condo it won't be as efficient as you might think. If your condo is heated with a heat pump, it could still be worthwhile even if it's inside.

Comment: @KMJ - This room is inside the unit and heated. Is cooler air better?

Comment: Warm air is fine. The problem is that during heating season, this unit is going to be pulling heat from the room that was put in there by your normal heating system. So if you live somewhere like Florida where you're using A/C most of the year, a heat pump water heater will be great. If you're in North Dakota, you're going to be just effectively doing a very roundabout version of heating the water with whatever fuel your regular heat system uses.

Comment: @KMJ - I see, thank you for that explanation. It's baseboard heating, which we're considering replacing with in-wall heaters in the future. Perhaps we'd add a standalone unit with its own thermostat at that point as well. Also, we're in a pretty mild climate (Seattle area), so winters aren't all that cold most of the season. Below freezing only for a few weeks, except at nights.

Comment: If you're using electric resistance heat to heat the space, part of the year the heat pump water heater will be no more efficient than a regular water heater, and it's noisier and more expensive. I'd skip it unless you're really interested in the dehumidifying effect you get for free with these units.

Comment: A hybrid will be a lot taller than your current heater, so it may need to be installed further from the wall that has the plumbing/wiring, shifting your side table out of the way.

Comment: Also, where does the piping from the overpressure/overtemp release valve on top go? Into the wall and outside somehow? There are code rules for that, so replacing the wh may involve plumbing mods.  Are you wanting to do this yourself, or hire a plumber?

Answer (score 0):

Condos can have challenges and surprises.

If you are on the second floor or higher, there may be a drain built into the pan that isn't evident until the tank is removed. If you don't have that drain, perhaps you can tie into the AC drain.  I will let the plumbing experts answer on tying into the washer drain.  In my local it isn't allowed.

The other issue is the electrical needs.  Be sure you can get the power to the unit you want without a great expense.

Comment: A hybrid will be just fine electrical needs wise since there's an electric heater here already. They usually use exactly the same size circuits (due to the backup heating element, which you can disable in software if you don't want it coming on) and draw much less when in heat pump mode.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,  I am not familiar with the electrical needs of Hybrids.